# React Native FBSDK IOS build is failing

Tags: ios, xcode

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow", referenced from:
_RAND_poll in libcrypto.a(rand_unix.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

React Native version: 0.63
Xcode version: 11.3.1
react-native-fbsdk: 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

## 1° Solution (Recommended):

I also have this problem, it seems to occur in the Xcode 11.3.1 version. One way to fix is updating the version to 11.6.

## 2° Solution:

- Comment all flipper function in podfile

[image: Print Podfile]

- Remove the function **InitializeFlipper** and **Imports** from appDelegate:

[image: Print Xcode]

- Run pod install:

[image: Print terminal]

- Clean project;
- Try again: `react-native run-ios`

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. I downgraded the react-native version from 0.63 to 0.61 which solved the problem